# Work mechanism and added value of higher speed of simple sprinklers?

Tags: lawn, watering, sprinkler-system

What is the use of higher rotating speed of standard lawn sprinklers (assuming there is a large family of similar non-special devices) you see around in Northern Western Europe and many other places? Do they pump more water per hour then maybe?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'standard lawn sprinklers' please? In the UK, we just used a hosepipe connected up to a stand alone sprinkler which is removed and stored afterwards, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Bamboo yes, thanks, it is if you can tune rotation speed at least in two modes, or is the speed just depending on the pressure?

Comment: Its almost entirely dependent on the water pressure I'm afraid - some do have settings, and you might find that one setting produces a spray which seems to have a lot of water, but in reality, its the same amount but restricted by, say, a targeted, narrow distribution hole which gives that appearance.

Comment: @Bamboo - now we have it - so what is the sense of having this setting?

Comment: Well,  I used a sprinkler today that has 6 different settings - these refer to the pattern of the spray. One of the settings is bi-directional, meaning the water comes out in two strong streams to the right and left only, and that looks like its pushing out more water, but its not,  its just directing the same amount differently. Basically, if you have poor water pressure, the sprinkler won't be very efficient, whatever setting it's on, and the only way of increasing water flow is to open the tap (or faucet depending where you live) at the other end of the hose more.